# Need to align the check box, add multiple records and view the datefiled while edit in extjs4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, extjs4

1. I need to add one or more records at a time in grid. After click on the add button i can able to add one record at a time. but he thing is i need to add multiple record at a time.
   I tried to use both clickToEdit, clicksToMoveEditor but not working.
2. I need to align the check box in center while edit the grid.
3. Main thing is while i able edit in grid i can able to only the fields except startdate and end date column. it not rendered from the database.

Can anyone help me if there is wrong config params for the grid.

```
this.mcmRowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            autoCancel: true,
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                canceledit: function(editor, event) {
                    if(!editor.record.get('FocusMarketId')) { //if it was a brand new record
                        console.log("edit");
                        console.log(editor.record.get('Id'));
                        var sm = this.mcmGridPanel.getSelectionModel();
                        App.mcmFocusMarketStore.remove(sm.getSelection());
                        if(sm.getCount()) {
                            sm.select(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });


var addFocusMarket = function(focusmarket) {
this.mcmRowEditing.cancelEdit();
console.log("add focus market");
var record = new Sch.model.Resource({
Id: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Id : '', 
Origin: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Origin : '',
Destination: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Destination: '',
CabinClass: focusmarket ? focusmarket.CabinClass: '',
StartAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.startAvailability: '', 
EndAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.endAvailability: ''
});
console.log("records-->"+record);
App.mcmFocusMarketStore.insert(0, record);
this.mcmRowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
this.mcmHasChanges = true;
};

this.mcmGridPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            height: 240,
            width: 540,
            title: 'Results',
            store: App.mcmFocusMarketStore,
            multiSelect: true,
            x: 0,
            y: 170,
            columns: [
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Flight#', sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'FlightNumber', hidden: true, 
                    editor: {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            maxLength: 4,
                            minLength: 4,
                            maxChars: 4,
                    }
                },
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Origin',  sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'Origin', 
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        maxLength: 3,
                        minLength: 3,
                        maxChars: 3,
                    }
                },  
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Destination',  sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'Destination',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        maxLength: 3,
                        minLength: 3,
                        maxChars: 3,
                    }
                },  
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Cabin',  sortable: true, width: 80, dataIndex: 'CabinClass', 
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                            maxLength: 1,
                            minLength: 1,
                            maxChars: 1,
                    }
                },
                { xtype: 'datecolumn', text: 'Start Date', width: 100, dataIndex: 'StartAvailability', format: 'd/m/Y',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        format: 'd/m/Y'
                    }
                },
                { xtype: 'datecolumn', text: 'End Date', width: 100, dataIndex: 'EndAvailability', format: 'd/m/Y', 
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        format: 'd/m/Y'
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    text: 'Delete?',
                    header: 'Delete?',
                    dataIndex: 'delete',
                    width: 60,
                    renderer: function (value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        return '<center><input type="checkbox" id="Delete-' + rowIndex + '"/></center>';
                    },
                    listeners : 
                    {
                        checkchange : function(column, recordIndex, checked) 
                                    {
                                       this.mcmRemoveFocusMarket();
                                        //or send a request
                                    } 
                    },
                    handler: function() {
                       /* var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                        rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                        store.remove(sm.getSelection());
                        if (store.getCount() > 0) {
                            sm.select(0);
                        }*/
                    },
                    //disabled: true,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'checkbox'
                    }

                }
            ],
            tbar: [
                {
                    text: 'Add',
                    tooltip: 'Add Focus Market',
                    iconCls: 'icon-shift-add',
                    scope: me,
                    handler: function() {
                            addFocusMarket.call(me);
                    }
                }
            ],
            plugins: [ this.mcmRowEditing ],
```

Answer (score 0):

1.)
Do not add records into the grid directly.
Add data to the backend and reload the store of the grid then to show newly added data in the grid

2)
Alignment should be fixed with the use of checkcolumn

3)
I am not really sure what you are asking here.
Editing seems to work from what I understand.
Are you sure you are providing data for datecolumns in the right format (date: '2014/02/04')?

```
// Presuming you are using ExtJS 4...
this.mcmRowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing',
{
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    autoCancel: true,
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        edit: function(editor, context, eOpts){
            // do your editing processing here
            // lookup api documentation for params
        }
    }
});

this.mcmGridPanel =  Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',
{
    height: 240,
    width: 540,
    title: 'Results',
    store: App.mcmFocusMarketStore,
    multiSelect: true,
    x: 0,
    y: 170,
    columns: [
        { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Flight#', sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'FlightNumber', hidden: true, 
            editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    maxLength: 4,
                    minLength: 4,
                    maxChars: 4,
            }
        },
        { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Origin',  sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'Origin', 
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                maxLength: 3,
                minLength: 3,
                maxChars: 3,
            }
        },  
        { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Destination',  sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'Destination',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                maxLength: 3,
                minLength: 3,
                maxChars: 3,
            }
        },  
        { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Cabin',  sortable: true, width: 80, dataIndex: 'CabinClass', 
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                    maxLength: 1,
                    minLength: 1,
                    maxChars: 1,
            }
        },
        { xtype: 'datecolumn', text: 'Start Date', width: 100, dataIndex: 'StartAvailability', format: 'd/m/Y',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                format: 'd/m/Y'
            }
        },
        { xtype: 'datecolumn', text: 'End Date', width: 100, dataIndex: 'EndAvailability', format: 'd/m/Y', 
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                format: 'd/m/Y'
            }
        },
        { xtype: 'checkcolumn', text: 'Delete?', width: 60, dataIndex: 'delete', format: 'd/m/Y', 
            // Make checkboxes of checkcolumn unchangeable. Editor can change state then.
            // Handle changes in CellEditing/RowEditing 'edit' event for consistent behavior with other columns.
            listeners: {beforecheckchange: function(column, recordIndex, checked){return false}}
            editor: {xtype: 'checkbox'},
            // checkcolumn aligns center by default use the 2 lines below instead if you want to align left
            //align: 'left',
            //editor: {xtype: 'checkbox', style: 'text-align:left; display:inline; padding-left:10px;'},
        }
    ],
    tbar: [
        {
            text: 'Add',
            tooltip: 'Add Focus Market',
            iconCls: 'icon-shift-add',
            scope: me,
            handler: function() {
                    addFocusMarket.call(me);
            }
        }
    ],
    plugins: [ this.mcmRowEditing ]
});
```